# Merge two results from Graph Api

Tags: c#, arrays, microsoft-graph-api

I am using Microsofts Graph Api to get devices connected via Intunes. I want to merge the result from managed Device and Registered Device. But they are two different objects. How can i merge an array of type Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject with an object of type Microsoft.Graph.ManagedDevice?

```
public async Task<Array> GraphAsync() { 

            try
            {
                var graphClient = ClientFactory.GetGraphApiClient();


                var uniqueUserId = ClaimsHelper.GetUniqueUserIdFromClaims();

                var managedDevices = graphClient.Users[uniqueUserId].ManagedDevices;
                var registeredDevices = graphClient.Users[uniqueUserId].RegisteredDevices;

                var resultManaged = await managedDevices.Request().GetAsync();
                var resultRegistered = await registeredDevices.Request().GetAsync();


                 Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject [] devices = resultRegistered.ToArray();
                 Microsoft.Graph.ManagedDevice [] devicesToAdd = resultManaged.ToArray();

                 int array1OriginalLength = devices.Length;
                 Array.Resize<Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject>(ref devices, array1OriginalLength + devices.Length);
                 Array.Copy(devicesToAdd, 0, devices, array1OriginalLength, devicesToAdd.Length);


                return devices;

            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                throw new UnauthorizedException(e + "Error calling GraphClient.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Both Microsoft.Graph.DirectoryObject and Microsoft.Graph.ManagedDevice are different types, so it is not possible to create copy objects of type ManagedDevice into an array of type DirectoryObject or vice versa. Both types inherit from the class Microsoft.Graph.Entity. So you can create an new array of type Entity and copy items of both array to the new array:

```
        DirectoryObject[] devices = new DirectoryObject[2];

        DirectoryObject directoryObject = new DirectoryObject();
        directoryObject.DeletedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;

        devices[0] = directoryObject;

        ManagedDevice[] devicesToAdd = new ManagedDevice[2];

        ManagedDevice managedDevice = new ManagedDevice();

        devicesToAdd[0] = managedDevice;

        Entity[] entityArray = new Entity[devices.Length + devicesToAdd.Length];
        Array.Copy(devices, entityArray, devices.Length);
        Array.Copy(devicesToAdd, 0, entityArray, devices.Length, devicesToAdd.Length);

        foreach(var entity in entityArray)
        {
            if(entity is DirectoryObject)
            {
                var castedObject = (DirectoryObject)entity;

                var dateTime = castedObject.DeletedDateTime;
            }

            if(entity is ManagedDevice)
            {

            }
        }
```

Keep in mind, that due to the type change properties or method specific to DirectoryObjects or ManagedDevice are no longer accessible. You will need to cast back to the specific type to use them, as shown in the foreach loop. Therefore, it may be better to have the function return a more complex type such as a custom class or a tuple of the two arrays, if you plan to use type specific properties to avoid casting.